# iPhone 6 Plus で `box-shadow` が transition 中に レンダリングしない

Tags: css, iphone, safari

`translate` で 移動させている際に `box-shadow` の描画が消えてしまい
transition が終了されると再描画されるという現象に悩んでます。。

`box-shadow` 自体がレンダリングされないというバグの報告は幾つかあるのですが、
transition 中にだけ消えるので困っています

誰かご助力お願いします。

iOS は 8.0.2 です。

Answer (score 2):

すみません。。質問しといてなんなんですが、解決しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407299/ios-8-box-shadow-on-iphone-6-plus

にありますとおり、

`border-radius: 1px`

をつけると解決しました。
1px がミソで 0 とかだと意味ないようですね。

編集してくださった h2so5 氏に感謝しつつクローズします。